# Sending multipart data with rauth / requests

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests, multipartform-data, rauth

I am developing an API-Client for transferring real estates.
The interface provided is using Oauth1 and multipart HTTP posts in order to upload attachment data.
The service provider wants to have attachments uploaded in a certain format as described here:
http://api.immobilienscout24.de/our-apis/import-export/attachments/post.html
(section *Example for picture*)
What I basically need to do is to create a MIME multipart post for

1. An XML document
2. A binary file

So far, I tried to use the file argument of `rauth`, resp. `requests` to deliver both, the XML and the binary file. But I cannot figure out how to add the different MIME types (e.g. application/xml and image/jpeg) to the respective multipart sections.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
import requests

files = {
    'attachment': ('filename.jpg',
           open('path/to/filename.jpg', 'rb'),
           'image/jpeg; name=filename.jpg',
           {'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary'}),
    'metadata': ('body.xml',
           open('/path/to/body.xml', 'rb'),
           'application/xml; name=body.xml',
           {'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary'})}

response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```